# installing and using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Whenever i use MySQL in my ASP.net project (database first) i get that my project uses the latest entity framework and that there is no provider for this version installed even though I just installed the latest MySQL connector?

Currently i have tried deleting entity framework, using a different database provider (microsoft sql server - failed to login using windows authentication for some reason), creating a new project and i don't know what more.

What do I have to do to make it work? 
When i install entity framework 5 it hands me the error that it somehow still references version 6 although version 6 never got installed.
Thanks,
g3.

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, you must have to make some changes in web.config. although i was using ef5 with .net 4.0

Comment: MySQL has a large guide about this.  Have you looked through it?  Quite possibly section 5.11 is what you need.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem is: I already have the database  and I'd like to import it into my project.